# io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView vs io.flutter.view.FlutterView

Tags: android, flutter

When I build debug app I have io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView in my view hierarchy. But when I build release it is io.flutter.view.FlutterView

How can I control this behaviour?

When I have io.flutter.view.FlutterView it does not load my plugins also.